# Add shared compute gallery to Devtest Labs with PowerShell or Terraform and start a VM

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform

I have an image created in Azure compute gallery.  Here's what I do manually, I open my devtest labs, go to the configuration setting, attach my compute gallery and then I am able to add a VM using a custom image in my compute gallery, and start it.  Everything works fine.  Now what I need to do is to repeat this process using script (either Terraform or Az Powershell).

Problem 1: I looked through both Terraform and Az Powershell documents and cannot find documents on how to attach a compute gallery to devtest labs.
[This image shows where I want to attach compute gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3teJs.png)

Problem 2 (Resolved): Assuming compute gallery is already attached manually, when creating a custom image vm using Az Powershell, I got an error
policyviolated: Requested gallery image is not authorized for this lab.
The script I used is from this official link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-vm-powershell
This script works for me when using a marketplace image.  What I did is to replace sku, publisher, offer to the image in my compute gallery.
[this image shows where I grabbed the information and where I replaced the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IdFF.png)
If I add VM manually using the same image in the same devtest lab, I do not have any error.

Comment: Which API version are you using? The support wasn't there to pull images with `offer`, `sku` & `publisher` fields. 
You would need to pass the image resource id to create the VM. 
BTW, using images (not azure images) on SO while asking questions is pretty [bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: thanks for the input.  The create custom vm part is resolved now.  I used sharedImageId and it worked.